# In gvim, how do I create a shortcut to open a file using the gui file open dialog

Tags: file, vim

In gvim, when I open a file via the file menu I get my operating system's native GUI file open dialog.  In most other editors you can access this via a keyboard shortcut instead of going to the file menu.  But in gvim the shortcut (as it appears in the file menu) is `:edit` which is a "command line oriented" way of opening files, not a GUI for opening files.

Is there a command `:blah` that will start the file open dialog for me?  I know other, similiar such commands exist (for example `:set guifont=*` will open the GUI font selector.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:browse confirm e`

should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For Gvim on Windows, just hit "**Alt + F + O**" key combo (equivalent to typing ":browse confirm e").

Comment: This shortcut works only if you have the menu visible on gvim. `:set go+=m` shows menu.